# Swing Components not appearing on sign-in window

Tags: java, swing

I'm running the below code designed to create a signin window that the returns credentials to another part of the program when the button is clicked and closes itself, but I'm running into an issue where the components disappears until the method finishes. I'm sure this isn't quite proper programming. If there are any suggestions that would be great.
[Broken Window View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izXXf.png)->
[Correct Window View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8IDY.png)

```
private static Pair<String, String> signIn() {
        // Create a new JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sign In");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create components
        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        JTextField usernameField = new JTextField(20);
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
        JButton signInButton = new JButton("Sign In");

        // Create panel and add components
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(usernameLabel);
        panel.add(usernameField);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
        panel.add(passwordField);
        panel.add(signInButton);

        // Add panel to the frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


        // Create a flag to track if the sign-in button is clicked
        AtomicBoolean isSignInClicked = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        
        // Add ActionListener to the sign-in button
        signInButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
                isSignInClicked.set(true); // Set the flag to true
            }
        });

        // Wait until the sign-in button is clicked
        int i = 0;
        while (!isSignInClicked.get()) {
            try {
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(100); // Pause for a short time
                System.out.println(i);
                if (i > 100) {System.err.println("Timeout at 10 seconds"); break;} // Timeout condition
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Pair<String, String> results = new Pair<>(usernameField.getText(), passwordField.getPassword().toString());
        System.out.print(results);
        return results;
    }
```

I have tried a number of different threading options as well as using latch events, but nothing seems to make them appear no matter how I switch around the method.

Comment: Code like this, `while (!isSignInClicked.get()) {`, will block the Swing event thread, the EDT, rendering the GUI useless, and this is completely unnecessary as there is no need for this type of code. Swing is an event-driven library, meaning if you want to respond to an event, such as a button being pushed, you add a listener of some sort to a component, here an ActionListener to the button.

Comment: In fact, you shouldn't even be using a second JFrame as your sign-in window but rather a modal JDialog, which will pause the calling code until the dialog has been dealt with.

Comment: Or, use a [CardLayout](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/64-java-login-with-cardlayout)